# Should a REST-ful api be heavily tied to your domain model?

Tags: api, rest

Given the following classes (note: these classes are not under discussion, they just exist this way)

```
class Foo {}

class Bar {}

class Event {

  Foo foo;
  Bar bar;
  String event;

  public Event(Foo foo, String event){
    ..
  }

  public Event(Bar bar, String event){
     ..
  }
}
```

An event is tied to Foo or to Bar, but never to both.

Would you model your REST api like(which more or less feels natural to the user of your api):

```
POST /foo/{FOO-ID}/event
GET /foo/{FOO-ID}/event  --> gets the list of events for FOO with the given id
GET /foo/{ID}/event/{EVENT-ID}

POST /bar/{BAR-ID}/event
GET /bar/{BAR-ID}/event --> gets the list of events for BAR with the given id
GET /bar/{BAR-ID}/event/{EVENT-ID}
```

or would you prefer (which more or less reflects the domain model):

```
POST /event
GET /event?id=123&type=FOO --> gets the list events of for FOO with id = 123
GET /event?id=456&type=BAR --> gets the list of events for BAR with id = 456
GET /event/{EVENT-ID} 
GET /event --> not implemented, it would logically return ALL events(both FOO and BAR), but this has no business meaning
```

Which of the 2 api's is the 'most' REST-ful? And why?

Comment: The question of "most" RESTful is fraught with disagreement and opinion making it a poor candidate for the StackOverflow question and answer format.

Comment: There are frameworks using both solutions and also websites use both solutions, so which one do you like more? It is up to you.

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni so actually, they are both correct? Actually, that was my underlying question.

Comment: Who decides what is "correct", david? Roy Fielding seems to think that most of us are getting REST wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your model, `Event` is an entity and a resource all by itself.

The first approach sends a different message: from that standpoint, `Event` is a *subresource* of a `Foo` or `Bar`, meaning it depends on one of these to exist, and if its "parent" ceases to exist, so does it.

Now I don't think your model has such relationship. Sure an `Event` probably makes no sense without a `Foo`/`Bar`, but it does have meaning alone. Tomorrow, `Event`s may relate to other new entities, so it is `Event` who depends on them, `Event` should change when it begins to track them, not the other way around.

Lastly, the use of query parameters is common to algorithmic resources or as "scoping" filters for collections, your second scenario.

If `Foo` or `Bar`, as classes, had a property of type `Event`, then the first approach could be applied.

Both approaches are "RESTFul". Roughly, REST is about using the HTTP methods the proper way, and using unique URIs to identify unique resources. The thing is that the second approach better depicts your model (and its relationships) as a set of resources.